# Impossible to launch registration page, toString javalang error

Tags: java, android, tostring

I'm completely nex on Android development app, and I'm trying to create with my own skills a little app and today I'm facing to a nex error which was not present yesterday...

App is launching correctly but when I click on register or connection button, app is crashing and I can see on logcat the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at fr.app.faridsissaoui.myapplicationtinder.MainActivity$6.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:207)
```

Below is the entire code if someone could give me some help, I just understood that was from ".toSting()" but not able to correct this.

package fr.app.faridsissaoui.myapplicationfinder;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private cards cards_data[];
    private arrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    private int i;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String currentUId;

    private DatabaseReference usersDb;

    ListView listView;
    List<cards> rowItems;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        usersDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        checkUserSex();

        rowItems = new ArrayList<cards>();


        arrayAdapter = new arrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item, rowItems );


        SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);


        flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
            @Override
            public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
                // this is the simplest way to delete an object from the Adapter (/AdapterView)
                Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
                rowItems.remove(0);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {

                cards obj = (cards) dataObject;
                String userId = obj.getUserId();
                usersDb.child(oppositeUserSex).child(userId).child("connexions").child("nope").child(currentUId).setValue(true);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                cards obj = (cards) dataObject;
                String userId = obj.getUserId();
                usersDb.child(oppositeUserSex).child(userId).child("connexions").child("yep").child(currentUId).setValue(true);
                isConnectionMatch (userId);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {

            }
        });


        // Optionally add an OnItemClickListener
        flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
            }
        });

    }

    private void isConnectionMatch(String userId) {
        DatabaseReference currentUserConnectionsDb = usersDb.child(userSex).child(currentUId).child("connexions").child("yep").child(userId);
        currentUserConnectionsDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nouveau Match!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    usersDb.child(oppositeUserSex).child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("connexions").child("matches").child(currentUId).setValue(true);
                    usersDb.child(userSex).child(currentUId).child("connexions").child("matches").child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).setValue(true);
                }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){ }

        });

        }


    private String userSex;
    private String oppositeUserSex;
    public void checkUserSex(){
        final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        DatabaseReference maleDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Homme");
        maleDb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals (user.getUid())){

                    userSex = "Homme";
                    oppositeUserSex = "Femme";
                    getOppositeSexUsers();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });


        DatabaseReference femaleDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Femme");
        femaleDb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(user.getUid())){

                    userSex = "Femme";
                    oppositeUserSex = "Homme";
                    getOppositeSexUsers();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

    }

    public void getOppositeSexUsers(){
        DatabaseReference oppositeSexDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(oppositeUserSex);
        oppositeSexDb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists() && !dataSnapshot.child("connexions").child("nope").hasChild(currentUId) && !dataSnapshot.child("connexions").child("yep").hasChild(currentUId)) {
                   String profileImageUrl = "default";
                    if (dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue() != "default"){
                        profileImageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().toString();

                   }
                    cards item = new cards(dataSnapshot.getKey(), (String) dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(),  profileImageUrl);
                    rowItems.add(item);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });


    }


    public void logoutUser(View view) {
        mAuth.signOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return;

    }

    public void goToSettings(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("userSex", userSex);
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }
}
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Tell me which line is the line number 207 in `MainActivity.java:207`. And simply there you have a `NullPointer`

Comment: Check if your `databaseReference("Users")` first. Is `Users` exists?

Comment: Line 2017 is the last one below: if (dataSnapshot.exists() &&!dataSnapshot.child("connexions").child("nope").hasChild(currentUId) && !dataSnapshot.child("connexions").child("yep").hasChild(currentUId)) {
                   String profileImageUrl = "default";
                    if (dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue() != "default"){
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                            profileImageUrl = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue()).toString();

Comment: Hi, It seems to be working better since I deleted all database fields and created it all again.I thought that was not mandatory to create all field before in FirebaseDatabase.Many Thanks, I think that I will come back soon with another issue ;)